# Unselect ListView-items that are not in the field-of-view

Tags: wpf, listview

In a ListView, I want the selected items to be always visible (in the current field of view).

Example: 
I have six items in my ListView. Only (the top) five are visible. 
I select the first item. When I scroll down, this item is not visible anymore, but it remains selected.

I want to DEselect any item that goes out of the current view.

Comment: What is business purpose?   Why would a user want an item to get un-selected just because it went out of view.    I think you would need to implement your own scrolling to know what items are in view.

Comment: That's a valid question. I (ab)use the ListView for its functionality. It's not the control the end-user interacts with.

Comment: OK, but I am even more confused.  The problem statement reads like you are using the ListView as a UI control.

Comment: You might be able to use VirtualMode true and handle the RetrieveVirtualItem but the problem there is that call could happen for an item that is not in display as I think it caches some.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx

Comment: I am using the ListView, but only in collaboration with another custom control, which responds to any selected item. Therefore, it makes no sense to have selected items you cannot see. I have already written my own logic where I keep track of the items in view, and deselect items that fall out of it. Btw, the link you mentioned is for WinForms. But thanks anyway, I appreciate your effort!

Comment: Post you answer and mark it.  I would like to see how you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it manually, so it's more a workaround. 
I just keep track of the index...

```
public class ScrollIndexManager
{
private readonly int _viewableItemsCount;
private int _canScrollUpCount;
private int _canScrollDownCount;

public ScrollIndexManager(int viewableItemsCount)
{
    _viewableItemsCount = viewableItemsCount;
}

public bool HasChanged { get; set; }

public int BottomVisibleItemIndex
{
    get { return TopVisibleItemIndex + _viewableItemsCount - 1; }
}

private int _topVisibleItemIndex = 0;
public int TopVisibleItemIndex
{
    get { return _topVisibleItemIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            HasChanged = false;
            return;
        }
        _topVisibleItemIndex = value;

        HasChanged = true;
    }
}

public void SetCanScrollDown(int totalItemCount)
{
    _canScrollDownCount = totalItemCount - _viewableItemsCount;
}

public bool CanScrollUp()
{
    return _canScrollUpCount > 0;
}

public bool CanScrollDown()
{
    return _canScrollDownCount > 0;
}

public bool Increase()
{
    TopVisibleItemIndex--;
    return HasChanged;
}

public bool Decrease()
{
    TopVisibleItemIndex++;
    return HasChanged;
}

public void ScrolledUp()
{
    _canScrollUpCount--;
    _canScrollDownCount++;
}

public void ScrolledDown()
{
    _canScrollUpCount++;
    _canScrollDownCount--;
}
}
```